# Android: Overlay bitmap over background

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, overlay

I have a linear layout with a pattern as background. Now I want to add some bitmaps to the layout in such a way, that the background pattern shines through these bitmaps.

In Photoshop I would just set the blending mode of the bitmaps to overlay and that's it. Is it possible to achieve that in android too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ImageViews to hold your Bitmaps, you can set the opacity of them in the code like this:

```
iv.setAlpha([0-255]);
```

Alternatively, if the bitmaps are images that you have control over (like if they are static and not user-generated) then you could just edit the images to be partially transparent.

Comment: thanks, but reducing the alpha of the bitmap makes the bitmap "pale", this is not the same as overlaying it

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant because I was not familiar with the "overlay" feature of Photoshop. I do not believe Photoshop's overlay blend mode is natively reproducible in Android. That being said, if you post screenshots of what you are trying to accomplish, someone may be able to think of another way to make it work.